# How to improve the speed of a nested for loop for game physics

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, game-physics

I'm making a game with python (specifically using pygame to render) where in my physics engine I have a O(n^2) problem.
In my Engine object:

```
def step():

    for obj1 in self.objects:
        for obj2 in self.objects:
            if obj1.XY != obj2.XY: # You can't have the object bounce itself
                obj1,obj2 = Collision(obj1,obj2)
```

These loops happen every time the game loop runs
The nested for loop is really killing the fps when there are 100+ objects (10000 total iterations).
I was wondering if there was a faster way to iterate through all possible combinations and apply a function to that pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you fix this is by using smarter data structures, so that your algorithm is no longer quadratic.

Look into space partitioning in general, and quadtrees in particular (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (if you're doing 2D -- the 3D equivalent is the octree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: I like the answer. Note this is still a O(n^2) algorithm. But the n is the number of elements in the vicinity of your object. Also you can use geometrical hashing instead of quad/octtrees (basically the same idea).

Comment: Indeed, collision checks with quadtrees/octrees are still quadratic, but with a much (much) smaller N.

Comment: So to implement this i would need to add code to update the quadrant the object is in then check collisions with the objects in the same quadrant?

Comment: Almost. Dividing your space into quadrants would at best divide the number of checks by 4. The idea behind a quadtree is to further divide the quadrants into quadrants, and so on recursively until each leaf of the quadtree contains a manageable number of entities. As a result, you only have to check for collisions with other entities in the same leaf.

Comment: Just to be a pedant, you may also have to check neighbouring leaves for collisions on the boundary

Comment: This is a problem I'm tackling I'll post a new question if I can't find a good answer